# Adding the range of colorbar to a pandas subplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to add a colorbar to the right side of my plot. It should show the color to the current iteration :
[image]

the code for my custom colorbar:

```
BLUE = '#00549F'
LIGHT_BLUE = "#407FB7"
LIGHTER_BLUE = '#8EBAE5'
LIGHTEST_BLUE = '#C7DDF2'

cmap = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("n", [LIGHTEST_BLUE,LIGHTER_BLUE,LIGHT_BLUE,BLUE])
```

The plot shows the Force of a machine that repeats the same process like 3000 times. Now I want to color code the iteration number. Pandas offers the .plot(cmap=cmap) function which does that, but I don't know how to add the colorbar as an orientation for the viewer.

Code for the plots:

```
fig,axs =  plt.subplots(2,1,figsize=(10,8))

df_data_blanking_stempel.plot(legend=False,colormap=cmap,ax=axs[0])
axs[0].set_title('Stamp')
axs[0].set_ylabel('Force[Newton]')

df_data_blanking_niederhalter.plot(legend=False,colormap=cmap,ax = axs[1])
axs[1].set_ylabel('Force[Newton]')
axs[1].set_xlabel('Time')
axs[1].set_title('Blankholder')

plt.suptitle(r'\textbf{Force Trajectories}',fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

One idea I have, is to generate the colorbar with a heatmap and add adjust and add it later with photoshop. But I am sure there is a better solution.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Custom colorbars](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colorbar_only.html) can be created from just a colormap (optionally together with a norm).  Here is an example (as the question doesn't contain example data, some dummy labels are used):

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
import numpy as np

BLUE = '#00549F'
LIGHT_BLUE = "#407FB7"
LIGHTER_BLUE = '#8EBAE5'
LIGHTEST_BLUE = '#C7DDF2'
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("n", [LIGHTEST_BLUE, LIGHTER_BLUE, LIGHT_BLUE, BLUE])

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
for ax in axs:
    cbar = plt.colorbar(ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap), ax=ax, ticks=np.linspace(0, 1, 4))
    cbar.ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels(['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth'])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: custom colorbars]

To create a colorbar similar to the one of the example heatmap, one could use:

```py
plt.colorbar(ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=plt.Normalize(0, 850000)), ax=ax)
```